# A library can't opt out of null safety by default when compile flutter apk with gradle

Tags: flutter

When I compile flutter android apk using gradle like this:

```
fastlane android beta
```

shows this error:

```
   /source/cruise-open/android/gradlew clean assembleRelease -p .' was 1 instead of 0. (FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneShellError)
    > Task :clean
    > Task :app:clean UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :flutter_secure_storage:clean UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :fluttertoast:clean UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :package_info:clean UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :path_provider:clean UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :share:clean UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :shared_preferences:clean UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :uni_links:clean UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :url_launcher:clean UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :video_player:clean UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :wakelock:clean UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :webview_flutter:clean UP-TO-DATE
    
    > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:4:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
    // @dart = 2.8
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/wakelock_platform_interface-0.1.0+1/lib/messages.dart:4:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
    // @dart = 2.8
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
    don't support null safety:
    
     - package:hive
     - package:hive_flutter
     - package:state_notifier
     - package:fish_redux
     - package:crypto
     - package:path_provider
     - package:convert
     - package:pull_to_refresh
     - package:flutter_icons
     - package:flutter_slidable
     - package:http
     - package:logger
     - package:dio
     - package:flutter_html
     - package:http_parser
     - package:webview_flutter
     - package:csslib
     - package:html
     - package:flutter_layout_grid
     - package:chewie
     - package:chewie_audio
     - package:video_player
     - package:video_player_platform_interface
     - package:quiver
     - package:wakelock
     - package:shimmer
     - package:wakelock_platform_interface
    
    For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
    
    
    > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease FAILED
             *********************************************************
    WARNING: This version of path_provider will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
             See for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
             This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
             *********************************************************
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * Where:
    Script '/Users/dolphin/apps/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
    > Process 'command '/Users/dolphin/apps/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 23s
    14 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

what should I do to pass `--no-sound-null-safety` when compile android apk? And this is my Fastline setting:

```
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :test do
    gradle(task: "test")
  end

  desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Crashlytics Beta"
  lane :beta do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    crashlytics
  
    # sh "your_script.sh"
    # You can also use other beta testing services here
  end

  desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play"
  lane :deploy do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    pgyer(
        api_key: ENV['PGY_API_KEY'],
        user_key: ENV['PGY_USER_KEY']
    )
  end
end
```